# How to create show controller in AngularFire with new API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am new to angular and firebase and am having problems since the API was switched a few days ago. I have a coursesIndexController and a coursesShowController, the index works but the show does not. Here is the index:

```
myApp.controller('CoursesIndexController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URL) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/courses/');
        $scope.courses = $firebaseObject(ref);
    }
    );
```

My coursesShowController is giving me a lot more issues. I am not sure how I can pull out the particular entry.

```
myApp.controller('CoursesShowController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams, FIREBASE_URL) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/courses/');
        var courses = $firebaseArray(ref);
        var key = $routeParams.id.toString();
        console.log(courses.get({shortName: key}));
    }
 );
```

**I am trying to return 1 course where the shortName matches the key in the address bar.** $routeParams.id.toString() returns a text string of that key just fine, but I get an "undefined is not a function" error when it tries to pull a course. For what it is worth, the key for each course is a timestamp so the "key" I am pulling is in the object itself.

I loop over the courses with this html snippet:

```
  <div class="course" class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="course in courses" >
    <p><a ng-href="#/courses/{{course.shortName}}">{{course.name}}</a></p>
  </div><!-- courses list -->
```

Thanks so much for the help!

EDIT: Here is what my courses firebaseArray looks like when I console.log it:
[image]

EDITx2: I can return a single object directly by the following command but I still do not know how to retrieve it by shortName in the object:

```
console.log($firebaseObject($scope.courses.$ref().child('-JWT5y43YFy1mGirVVS2')));
```

Comment: $firebaseObject is fetching data from the server. You have to wait for the values to return before trying to read them. In general, put it in the scope and use it in the view, stop trying to console.log async values.

Comment: Is it better practice to pull the firebaseArray and then search through it for the shortName that matches my routeParams OR to pull the correct firebaseObject correctly? What would be the code to do either of those? Thanks, this was helpful!

Comment: [The guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/) covers all these topics in detail, including a section on async ops in the getting started section. I'd dig in there. In general, if you already know the record id, just fetch it with $firebaseObject.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$getRecord()` instead of `get()`? Noted in the AngularFire docs [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey). Your code slightly altered for `$getRecord()` below:

```
myApp.controller('CoursesShowController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams, FIREBASE_URL) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/courses/');
        var courses = $firebaseArray(ref);
        var key = $routeParams.id.toString();
        console.log(courses.$getRecord({shortName: key}));
    }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I use the get record function you specified, I get back a null. I added a photo with my courses array above if that makes it easier.

Comment: What I show in the image above in my post. First there are several objects, each is a course and then there are a ton of methods.

Comment: hmmm. I'm wondering if $getRecord() requires the $id. If you ran `console.log(courses.$getRecord("-JWT5y43YFy1mGirVVS2"));` I wonder what you'd get.

Comment: I get null again! That is insanity, I would have thought for sure that this last option should have worked.

Comment: When you `console.log(courses)` can you check to see if `$getRecord` is one of the methods that appears? Based on your above screenshot I see that `$add`, `$save`, `$remove`, and `$keyAt` are available. Speaking of, what does `console.log(courses.$keyAt(0));` return?

Comment: I updated picture to show that $getRecord indeed is a method in courses. When I type console.log(courses.$keyAt(0)); I get a null return.

Answer (score 0):

Try enumerating the array, searching for the right object:

```
myApp.controller('CoursesShowController', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams, FIREBASE_URL) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/courses/');
        var courses = $firebaseArray(ref);
        var key = $routeParams.id.toString();
        var course;
        for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
            if (courses[i].shortName === key) { 
                course = courses[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(course);
    }
 );
```

Comment: When I type: console.log(courses[0]); that returns a null so iterating over the length doesn't help me either.